# Pragma optimize gives errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I would like to use the `pragma` optimize in a function called `image()` that I have created:

```
#pragma optimize("", off)
image();
#pragma optimize("", on)
```

> Error 2   error C2156: pragma must be outside function    C:....\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\ex4\ex4.cpp  1038
>
> Error 4   error C2156: pragma must be outside function    C:....\Visual
>   Studio 2010\Projects\ex4\ex4.cpp  1040

I didn't find out how it would be possible to resolve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thes `#pragma`s should be placed around the function definition of `image`, not when you call it. Also, note that your order of `off` and `on` will *disable* optimizations for `image`. For example:

```
#pragma optimize("", off)
void image()
{
  // ...
}
#pragma optimize("", on)
```

This will disable the default optimizations (according to the `/O` compiler option) for the duration of `image`.